# Are other Groots also named "Groot"?

Tags: marvel, guardians-of-the-galaxy, groot

Assuming that Groot is not the only Groot who ever grooted, are the other Groots also named "Groot"?

If they *are* all named "Groot", it is the same "Groot" or is there a distinction in their names that we can't hear, just like for everything else that Groots groot?

---

Related: [What Species is Groot?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82085/what-species-is-groot)

Comment: https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/marveldatabase/images/3/32/Flora_colossus_from_Annihilators_Vol_1_1.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140717004206

Comment: @Valorum:   I saw this, but it doesn't actually tell me if their names are all *Groot*.   It just tells me it sounds like "I am Groot" when they speak.

Comment: Thor speak Groot and identifies Groot's name as "Tree"

Comment: Maybe the Groots are all one Groot at the root, like [Pando](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pando_(tree)).

Comment: They are all Groots: Papa Groot, Hefty Groot, Brainy Groot, Grootette,... there are also female Groots but they haven't been seen for a long time. Oh wait, I think I am confusing...

Comment: Groot's name is not actually Groot, everyone calls him Groot because all he says is "I am Groot"

Comment: [This other question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/144324/were-the-smurfs-the-first-to-smurf-their-smurfs), while not actually a duplicate, needs to be mentioned here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In *Annihilators Vol 1* Issue 1 Rocket travels to Planet X, Groot's homeworld, and meets a bunch of other Groots. One of the Groots refers to himself as King Groot and Groot XXCVII which implies that all of the Groots are called Groot. In fact when he talks about other Groots he again mentions it like they are all named Groot *"His highness believes the Groot you are referring to is one of the tearaways"*.

> [image: Annihilators Vol 1 Issue 1 relevant page transcribed below]
>
> **Rocket:** Hold on, Hold On! I used to be able to understand my old buddy, but your accents are so strong! Where is it, flarking gadget?
>
> **Rocket:** Voice command: activate!
>
> **Timely Inc. analyzer:** I am the property of Timely Inc. Mail Division, and must be returned as soon as--
>
> **Rocket:** Yeah, yeah! All in good time! I need you to do a little translation work.
>
> **King Groot:** I AM GROOT!
>
> **Timely Inc. analyzer:** He is saying his name is Groot.
>
> **Rocket:** Duh. He's not my Groot. My Groot wasn't a mile-high super Reedwood. I'm looking for King Groot.
>
> **King Groot:** I AM GROOT!
>
> **Timely Inc. analyzer:** He is wondering why you've disturbed the inner circle of the Arbor Masters. He is King Groot, Groot XXCVII, Royal Loftiness of Planet X, Custodian of the Branch Worlds and Ruler of All he Shades.
>
> **Rocket:** That's not possible...
>
> **Timely Inc. analyzer:** His highness believes the Groot you are referring to is one of the tearaways, the youngsters who live their lives at a faster pace than the slow-growing matures. He is saying that the sapling in question ran off some years back, and travelled the galaxy, claiming he was monarch of Planet X.
>
> **Rocket:** But he came back. Groot came home again, right?
>
> **King Groot:** I AM GROOT!
>
> **Timely Inc. analyzer:** His highness replies that the sapling did return. On arrival, he was arrested and tried for his crimes of deception and impersonating the king.

However, in *Infinity Countdown* Issue 1 we meet a "Groot" who goes by the name of Scar and can talk properly it seems. So not all Groots are named Groot.

> [image: Infinity Countdown Issue 1 page transcribed below]
>
> **Unknown Guardian:** ...we have our own big problem.
>
> **Scar:** The reign of meatbags is over! Scar will return Telferina to its floral glory!

Comment: @DavidW It is supposed to be floral, probably just a play on words.

Comment: @DavidW Well it went completely over my head!